Timer trigger for Azure Functions
I would like to ask for every 30 min we can put
0 */30 * * * * 

or
0 30 * * * *

what if I want to make the time start at 15 min for every 30 minutes?
Eg:
12:15,12:45,13:15,13:45,14:15,14:45....
I am expecting the time trigger to execute the program start at 12:15 minutes and run every interval of 30 minutes

15 */1 * * * your_command  specifies that the job should run at 15 minutes past every hour
, 45 */1 * * * your_command specifies that the job should run at 45 minutes past every hour.

Please let me know if the below answer works for you.

Azure Functions uses the NCronTab library to interpret NCRONTAB expressions such as:
0 15,45 * * * *

This means that the function will be triggered every minute 15 or 45.
Using NCrontab Expression Tester to validate the expression:

You can also limit the time period when the function should run - for example, between 12 and 15 hours:
0 15,45 12-15 * * *


See NCRONTAB expressions for more details.
